# How to show the relation link between classes in UML class diagrams?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, uml

I am using IntelliJ IDEA to view the UML class diagram. The relation link between class and trait is shown but the relation link between classes is not (like the pic below).

When I create a relationship link manualy, it hints that I cannot create relation link because relationship already exists.

How can I show the relation link between the classes?

PS: This is a scala project. I also tried java project and everything went well.

[image]